# Camel exceptions unmarshalling JAXB ISO-8859-1 XML file

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel

For my route I set:

```
    String encoding = "iso-8859-1";
    JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat( Data.class.getPackage().getName() );

    if( encoding != null) {
        jaxb.setEncoding( encoding );
    }

    from( "file://" + location + "?charset=" + encoding )
    .routeId(this.getClass().getSimpleName()) // Give a nice name
 . etc.
```

then when I provide the file in this ISO encoding I get an exception stack:

```
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc (at char #3964, byte #127)]
java.io.IOException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xfc (at char #3964, byte #127)]
    at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.unmarshal(JaxbDataFormat.java:153)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Essentially this error is reporting that a special character is present and it doesn't like it

Comment: I must not be setting the iso-8559-1 encoding correctly but I don't know what it should be - I can't find better information from camel jaxb

Comment: I keep getting down-votes on this question, but can't delete it either. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Camel doc](http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html), `jaxb.setEncoding` will not help, as this parameter is only used when marshalling XML documents but not when unmarshalling them.

In the ideal world, the encoding declaration in the prolog (first magic line in XML file) matches the actual encoding of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

This information is (or at least should be) automatically used by the file reading utility such as JAXB.

`0xfc` is a ISO-8859-1 encoded `ü`. In your case, check the prolog encoding declaration. If it doesn't say `ISO-8859-1` it is faked. Ask the producer of the file (I hope, it wasn't you...) to set the declaration accordingly. Normally, this is correctly done by the XML marhalling framework.

If you cannot convince the producer of the file to set the correct declaration, then the things are getting trickier. In this case, you must know or guess the encoding and setting the camel header accordingly in the route:

```
.setHeader(Exchange.CHARSET_NAME, "ISO-8859-1")
```

According to the source code of `JaxbDataFormat` ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-jaxb/2.12.3/org/apache/camel/converter/jaxb/JaxbDataFormat.java#JaxbDataFormat.unmarshal%28org.apache.camel.Exchange,java.io.InputStream%29)), this encoding is only taken into account if the `filterNonXmlChars` property of the `JaxbDataFormat` instance is set to `true`:

```
jaxb.setFilterNonXmlChars(true);
```

Alternatively, you may also set the `Exchange.FILTER_NON_XML_CHARS` property to `true`.

Comment: Exactly, you set

jaxb.setFilterNonXmlChars( true );

And it works. The setEncoding you're right, has no effect it was that line above that I needed. Thanks